# how do i redirect to any other page for json request type?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

my application redirects the user to the login page whenever there is no session. But for Ajax request this redirecting is not happening.

I need to handle this redirection issue for all ajax calls in the application.

Comment: What is your server side language? Why do you think it is not happening?

Comment: my server side language is java and the request type is json. It is redirecting to login page (if i observer in firebug). But the screen is not reloaded.

Comment: @GRM are you using jQuery or some other library?

Comment: yes, jquery library is used.

Comment: I am able to redirect to login page single ajax request using window.location in ajax success method. But my application has many ajax requests. One single page has 15 to 30 ajax requests. this will difficult to handle each request. Need to handle all ajax requests with minimal code.

Answer (score 1):

I were doing similar thing on Zend/PHP project. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Java and there I can suggest only basic direction.

By default, XMLHttpRequest execute redirects. So if you do a redirect during ajax request, XMLHttpRequest will execute it without letting you know that redirect happened at all. At least I found no way to catch such situation and handle it somehow. Because of that, on server side I override a redirect method. Suppose you can do something like that in Java too. Once request came from ajax (you can add a some specific header to your ajax request and check it on server) you can return a header different from `Location` header. For instance, `New-Location`, and do no actual redirect. Just stop request execution.

On client side you can use [jQuery.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to configure global handler for all ajax requests at once. 
Here is how you can add a header to all requests with `.ajaxSetup`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        XHTTPRequest: 'true'
    }
});
```

Additionally you can set a global [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) and [ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) handlers. They will be executed before any success/error handler of a separate ajax request. In global ajax success you can take a header from `xhr` object passed as a third parameter to callback function and do a redirect:

```
var newLocation = xhr.getResponseHeader("New-Location");
if(newLocation)
     document.location = newLocation;
```

Basically, you can return special object instead of header or find some other way to pass a new location to your `ajaxSuccess` callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **window.location** in AJAX success block to redirect the user to the target page.

Comment: Hi Wasim, this implementation is good for single Ajax request. But in my application many ajax requests are there. for example one single page has 15 to 30 ajax requests. this will difficult to handle each request. Need to handle all ajax requests with minimal code.

Answer (score 0):

The way i do it:

At the **server** side:

```
    define('BASE_URL','http://www.yourdomain.com');

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'){
        // if it's an ajax request

        $json['success'] = 1;
        $json['redirect'] = BASE_URL.'/logout';
        echo json_encode($json);
    }else{
        // if it's an non ajax request


    }
```

At the **client** side using jquery:

```
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: 'www.yourdomain.com',

              data: {test: 1},
              complete: function(e, xhr, settings){
                  switch(e.status){
                      case 500:
                         alert('500 internal server error!');
                         break;
                      case 404:
                          alert('404 Page not found!');
                         break;
                      case 401:
                          alert('401 unauthorized access');     
                         break;       
                  }
              }
            }).done(function( data ) {

                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data)

                if (obj.success == 1){
                     var url = obj.redirect;
                     location.href = url;
                }

            });
```

Comment: Hi, this implementation is good for single Ajax request. But in my application many ajax requests are there. for example one single page has 15 to 30 ajax requests. this will difficult to handle each request. Need to handle all ajax requests with minimal code.